# Should I change my 2005 Honda Accord's transmission fluid?

Tags: transmission, maintenance, transmission-fluid

I just bought a 2005 Honda Accord EX-L v6 this last week. It has about 180k miles. I'm doing maintenance on it like changing oil, air filters, etc, but I'm nervous about changing my trans fluid. It isn't burnt or black, more of a darker reddish/orange color with no specs. So I'm assuming it was changed at some point in its history. I don't want it to slip as it's my daily driver for the forcible future. I really want to change it because of the known honda accord transmission issues, but I don't want to accidentally mess everything up.

Comment: Go to a good transmission shop and ask.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I don't see a question here to be honest, are you asking whether changing the fluid could harm the transmission, or whether you would benefit from a fluid change?

Comment: Someone on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQsVuUOK6Cg) comments *2006 Honda Accord transmission drain and refill. Replace automatic transmission fluid at 60k miles or 3 years, then replace every 30k miles or 2 years.* And [this dealer](https://www.normreeveshondacerritos.com/honda-accord-maintenance-schedule-los-angeles-ca/) says *Every 90,000 miles: Change transmission fluid.* They are different but the implication is you do it at regular intervals.

Comment: @WeatherVane The service manual says change at 120,000 miles. Of course "someone on YouTube" may be the same guy who insists that every car should have an  engine oil change every 3,000 miles :)

Comment: @alephzero the [Hindustan Ambassador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindustan_Ambassador) service guy?

Answer (score 1):

The manual states when the transmission fluid is supposed to be changed. It should be changed according to that. If you don't know when the last change was, it's a good idea to change it and then continue regular service guidelines. Some Hondas fluid change consists of drain, fill and drive a little and repeat twice for their fluid change. I don't know what procedure yours takes. It is very important that you use only the correct Honda transmission fluid in all Hondas.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MVMR, I hope you find my answer helpful Kade.
There is a transmission fluid filter as well which needs to be replaced along with the gasket. Some versions might include a large O'Ring. It's a good practise to change fluid every 20K mile to keep it fresh, filter every 40K mile. You should also check the valves, and solenoids to be certain. Mercedes-Benz and Porsche have high standards for transmission servicing. Toyota, Hyundai, Nissan, and Honda are not too keen on anything apart from a fluid change at 40k to 80k mile intervals.

If you are thinking that changing the fluid will damage the transmission, it is quite possible since it has 180k mileage and you don't have a service history. Nevertheless, by not servicing the transmission you are just buying time not a fix.

*filter is specific to your transmission variant
*fluid would be ATFZ from Idemitsu or Multi ATF from Motul would suffice. If you want top notch stuff use ZF lifeguard 6. Honda dealership will dump rebadged Idemitsu atf to you for 30% excess. Comment further, below this answer in case you have more queries or would like to elaborate.

Good luck.